# What format is the LVM config file?

Tags: perl, lvm

So here is a snippet from the config file I'd like to parse (It is an LVM2 Config):

```
VolGroup00 {
    id = "vyllep-rfI6-LCvO-h6mN-zYZu-hiAN-QShmG6"
        seqno = 3
        status = ["RESIZEABLE", "READ", "WRITE"]
        flags = []
        extent_size = 65536             # 32 Megabytes
        max_lv = 0
        max_pv = 0
        metadata_copies = 0

        physical_volumes {

                pv0 {
                        id = "1yLiSl-x0fp-ZkyU-HMQl-eTVt-xiId-cFnih0"
                        device = "/dev/xvda2"   # Hint only

                        status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
                        flags = []
                        dev_size = 31246425     # 14.8995 Gigabytes
                        pe_start = 384
                        pe_count = 476  # 14.875 Gigabytes
                }
        }
}
```

I would like to parse this into a Perl data structure. What format is this config in? My *guess* is it looks likes a python data structure.

Any thoughts the format, or better yet, an existent module to parse it with?

Comment: could be something specific to lvm2...

Comment: "looks likes a python data structure" makes no sense. Maybe you meant "looks like python code"? But it's my understanding that Python uses indentation instead of curlies, so I strongly doubt that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The config uses a custom config language specifically for LVM.  The lvm userspace tools include code to parse this language.

You could grab [the userspace code for lvm2](ftp://sources.redhat.com/pub/lvm2/) and attempt to replicate its parser, maybe using [Parse::RecDescent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parse::RecDescent).

Or maybe the [Perl Linux::LVM module in CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Linux::LVM) provides the functionality to extract the information you need.